# What happens to Chebyshev polynomials integration when n=1

Tags: integration, infinity, chebyshev-polynomials, singular-integrals

The integration of Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind has the following value,
$$\int T_{n}(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \left( \frac{T_{n+1}(x)}{n+1} - \frac{T_{n-1}(x)}{n-1} \right)$$
what happens when n=1? We have zero division.

Best, Mohd

Comment: Note that for $n=1$, $T_{n-1}(x)$ is just a constant, which means that as the result of an integral, it can effectively be ignored.

Comment: for n=1, T_{n-1}(x)=1, thus the second term will read 1/0.

Comment: After investigating this issue, I think the integration should have be as follows: When n=0, the result is x, and when n=1 the result is x^2/2, and for n>1 it is $$\int T_{n}(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \left( \frac{T_{n+1}(x)}{n+1} - \frac{T_{n-1}(x)}{n-1} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral really ought to read:

$$\int T_{n}(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \left( \frac{T_{n+1}(x)}{n+1} - \frac{T_{n-1}(x)}{n-1} \right)+C$$

and we can rewrite this as

$$\int T_{n}(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \left( \frac{T_{n+1}(x)}{n+1} - \frac{T_{n-1}(x)-1}{n-1} \right)+C'$$

Note now that L'Hopital's Rule gives us:

$$\lim_{n\to1}\left(\frac{T_{n-1}(x)-1}{n-1}\right)=\lim_{n\to1}\left(\frac{\cos((n-1)\arccos x)-1}{n-1}\right)=\lim_{n\to1}\left(\frac{-\arccos x\cdot\sin((n-1)\arccos x)}{1}\right)=0$$

Hence,

$$\int T_{1}(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \left( \frac{T_2(x)}{2} - 0 \right)+C'=\frac{T_2(x)}{4}+C'$$

There technically ought to be a bit more rigor involved in taking $n\to1$, but hopefully this explains the motivation somewhat.

Comment: I will have to disagree with this, this is because of moving the zero-division problem to C′. L'Hopital's worked fine for that term, still the constant will approach infinity.

Comment: The constant is arbitrary, it doesn't behave any way with a limit. For comparison, you can consider how $\int x^{-n}\, dx = \frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}+C$ behaves as $n\to1$.

Comment: So, which integral should one use if the integration is taken from x=0 to x=1? 
If the one you rewrote (the one with C′) is equivalent to the original, it should give the same answer, but it won't. 
you might be interested of having a look at my other question:
[link] http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640768/inner-product-of-chebyshev-polynomials-of-the-second-kind-with-x-as-weighting

Comment: Why won't it give the same answer? If you integrate it from $0$ to $1$ then the arbitrary constant just drops out. Note that $\frac{T_2(x)}{4}=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{4}$, which differs from your answer by a constant.